# How to draw a text using the bge module I

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

I´m trying to draw a text using the bge module.
This is my code:

```
# import game engine modules
from bge import render
from bge import logic
# import stand alone modules
import bgl
import blf


def init():
    """init function - runs once"""
    # create a new font object, use external ttf file
    font_path = logic.expandPath('//Zeyada.ttf')
    # store the font indice - to use later
    logic.font_id = blf.load(font_path)

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    scene.post_draw = [write]


def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = render.getWindowWidth()
    height = render.getWindowHeight()

    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = logic.font_id
    blf.position(font_id, (width * 0.2), (height * 0.3), 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")
```

I add an object, a sensor and a controller as you can see in the next picture:
[image]

But, when I pulse "p" on the 3D viewer screen and it´s suppose my game runs I only see this:
[image]

I´ve tried to change the text´s size and the frequency of the sensor.
Any idea about something that may be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve just realized that I don´t have the file called "Zeyada.ttf" so my problem is in the line:

```
 font_path = logic.expandPath('//Zeyada.ttf')
```

Apparently I need a ttf file to present the text and it makes sense, every text has format.