# How to draw a text using the bge module II

Tags: python, game-engine, text-object

I´m trying to draw a text using the bge module. After adding the path of the "Zeyada.ttf" file my code looks like this:

```
# import game engine modules
from bge import render
from bge import logic
# import stand alone modules
import bgl
import blf


def init():
    """init function - runs once"""
    # create a new font object, use external ttf file
    font_path = logic.expandPath('C://Documents and Settings//Guillermo//Mis documentos//Google Drive//Gproyectos//Proyectos con Blender/Zeyada.ttf')
    # store the font indice - to use later
    logic.font_id = blf.load(font_path)

    # set the font drawing routine to run every frame
    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    scene.post_draw = [write]


def write():
    """write on screen"""
    width = render.getWindowWidth()
    height = render.getWindowHeight()

    # OpenGL setup
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_PROJECTION)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()
    bgl.gluOrtho2D(0, width, 0, height)
    bgl.glMatrixMode(bgl.GL_MODELVIEW)
    bgl.glLoadIdentity()

    # BLF drawing routine
    font_id = logic.font_id
    blf.position(font_id, (width * 0.2), (height * 0.3), 0)
    blf.size(font_id, 50, 72)
    blf.draw(font_id, "Hello World")
```

The rest is as I put it [in my first question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98047/how-to-draw-a-text-using-the-bge-module-i).
I don´t know what is failing, why I don´t see anything.

Comment: A python controller set as script will run the script top to bottom, you define functions but don't call them.

Comment: @sambler: Please,post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A python controller will run the script from top to bottom, the same as if you were running any python script.

The code you show defines two functions but does not call them. I expect you need to add a call to the functions for your script to work.